# Priority within exceptions

Tags: java, exception

so i'm preparing for a mid term that involves exception handling. I for the life of me cant figure out the output of this multi catch that i have written.

```
 System.out.println("first try");
    try{
        int[] array = new int[24];
        array[array.length] = 30/0 ;
    }catch (ArithmeticException e){
        System.out.println("divide by zero");
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("array size problem");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("shouldnt be called");
    }
    System.out.println("second try");
    try{
        int[] array = new int[24];
        array[array.length] = 30/0 ;
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("array size problem");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("shouldnt be called");
    }
    System.out.println("third try");
    try{
        int[] array = new int[24];
        array[array.length] = 30/0 ;
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("array size problem");
    }
```

the thing with this is that with no combination of catches can i get the index out of bounds exception to show, so is this like an example of a hierarchy between the exceptions themselves? (or a more offput thought that is this because the computation part is done first, hence faces an exception first and hence thats what is caught).

Comment: I assume 30/0 throws an exception first so there is never an attempt to update the array and hence no ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: The code inside the 3 `try` blocks is **exactly the same**, so why would you expect them to throw different exceptions? --- *"Insanity is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting different results."*

Answer (score 0):

The array is never accessed in the code you wrote. As you suspected, the right hand side of the statement is calculated first, and throws an `ArithmeticException`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in this code then changing 30 / 0 to 30 / 1 can produce.

The most appropriate sub exception type if handled then code will catch that exception but in case not handled then it will catch by super type of that Exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("first try");
    try {
        int[] array = new int[24];
        array[array.length] = 30 / 1;// Not divide by zero rather referring array index that is out of bound.
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        System.out.println("divide by zero");
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("array size problem");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("shouldnt be called");
    }
    System.out.println("second try");
    try {
        int[] array = new int[24];
        array[array.length] = 30 / 0;
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("array size problem");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("shouldnt be called");
    }
    System.out.println("third try");
    try {
        int[] array = new int[24];
        array[array.length] = 30 / 0;
    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        System.out.println("array size problem");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
first try
array size problem
second try
shouldnt be called
third try
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at PerfectPower.main(PerfectPower.java:31)
```